# NodeJs fs find folder by partial name

Tags: node.js

Say I have folders that have ID's (eg. 123456, 654321). How can I find the folder with ID 123456 if I only have a portion of it (eg. 2345)?

Comment: Search similar posts on stackoverflow. You can use a regex among others, but there's lots of ways to get that info. Use your search skillz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use glob package to search.

```
const glob = require('glob');
const searchPattern = patternStr => glob(__dirname + `/**/*${patternStr}`, {}, 
(err, files)=>{
  if(err) return console.error(err);
  console.log(files);
})
```